# Does the equation $a^n+b^n=c^n$ have positive integer solutions?

Tags: integers, natural-numbers

We know that the equation $a^n+b^n=c^n$ has infinitely many positive integer solutions when $n=1,n=2$. Also, by Fermat's last theorem, we know that this equation has no positive integer solution for any integer value of $n$ greater than $2$.

My question is: Does the equation $a^n+b^n=c^n$ have positive integer solutions for non-integer $n>2$?

Say for example, $a^{2.5}+b^{2.5}=c^{2.5}$

Comment: There are very obviously very *very* many positive integer solutions by the intermediate value theorem if $n$ is not required to be an integer.

Comment: @Servaes "obviously" according to an intelligent person as you. Could you please provide some of those obvious solutions for $2<n<3$, please?

Comment: Well b00n heT has given that $4^2 + 5^2 > 6^2$ and $4^3 + 5^3 < 6^3$ so there must be an $2 < n < 3$ so that $4^n + 5^n = 6^n$.  Noone said anything about *finding* the solution just that there is one.  But as $f(x) =4^x + 5^x$ has a positive derivative that is strictly greater than the positive derivative  $g(x) =6^x$ we know a distinct real number *does* exist so... we did find it.  It's the real number where this is true.

Comment: Okay... if you question was does an integer solution exist for *all* real $n$, that could have been stated more clearly.   As the question is currently worded we took it to mean does *any* real $n$ have solutions.  And the answer to that is yes.

Comment: @fleablood dear guys, may be it is due my way of asking the question is not good, because I am Arabic. I not asking if we fix $a,b,c$ then will we get $n$ or no. I am asking if we fix $n$, then will there be positive integers $a,b,c$? Say we have $n=2.5$, can we find $a,b,c$? [converse of what many of you understood me, please edit my question if you got what I mean, thanks]

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari This is really just a basic application of the intermediate value theorem, which is of course nonconstructive. That is to say, it doesn't give you the value of such $n$, it just tells you that such an $n$ exists.

Comment: @Servaes can you please read my comment to fleablood?

Comment: As for your edited question; the answer is clearly no as there are only countably many triplets $(a,b,c)$ of integers, and uncountably many real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [1] obviously not for *every* non-integer $n$ will have integer solutions, $a,b,c$.

But obviously [2] *some* (many) integer $a,b,c$ will have non-integer $n$ solutions.

[1].  It'd be rather bizarre and strange if *none* of the $n\in \mathbb Z; n> 2$ will have integer solutions to $a^n + b^n = c^n$ but that *every* $\x \not \in \mathbb Z; x > 2$ will have integer solutions to $a^x + b^x = c^x$.

And it's obviously not true as there are uncountably many $x$ but only countably many triplets $(a,b,c)$.  [Each $x$ would have a unique  set of triplets as $a^x + b^x \ne a^y + b^y$ if $x\ne y$.]

[2]  If $a< c < b$ where $a^2 + b^2 > c^2$ there will be a value where $a^m + b^m < c^m$ and by intermediate value theorem the is an $x; 2 < m < x$ where $a^x + b^x = c^x$.

....

As for $a^{2.5} + b^{2.5} = c^{2.5}$, I highly suspect has no integer solutions.

==== old answer====

Suppose $a^k + b^k > c^k$ and $a^m + b^m < c^m$; $k, m \in \mathbb N$ and $k \ge 2$.

That would mean there is a $j\in \mathbb R; k < j < m$ so that $a^j + b^j = c^k$.

So for instance $4^2 + 5^2> 6^2$ but $4^3 +  5^3 = 189 <216 = 6^3$ so there must be a $j; 2 < j < 3$ where $4^j + 5^j = 6^j$.

As for any $x > 1$ we have $(a + b)^x > a^x + b^x$ we find can assure that for and $a < c < b$ we can have $a^x + b^x > c^x$ (although $x$ may be less than $2$) and there will be $y > x$ so that $a^y + b^y < c^y$ and $j; x < j < y$ where $a^j + b^j =c^j$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the function 
$$f_{a,b,c}(x)=a^x+b^x-c^x$$
with $a=4,b=5,c=6$. Then for $x=2$ the function is positive, while for $x\to\infty$ ($x=3$ is actually enough) the function will be negative. By continuity (intermediate value theorem) the function must at least one zero, i.e. a solution.

A similar argument will lead to various solutions.

Comment: I think, if your argument is true, then Fermat last theorem must be false. When $n$ is either $2$ or $2.5$, IVT should tell us that there is a solution. Or may be I misunderstand your argument.

Comment: I don't get your question. We are fixing $a,b,c$ and letting the exponent vary... By using the exponents $x=2,x=3$ we know that an exponent $x^\ast\in ]2,3[$ between these two must give us a solution of the form $$4^{x^\ast}+5^{x^\ast}=6^{x^\ast}$$

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Are you saying that if you fix the exponent and let the bases vary, there are solutions?  That is true, but the bases won't be integers.

Comment: For example. Let  $f(x)=4^x+5^x-6^x$ Then $f(2)=5$ and $f(3)=-27$. So there exists some $2 < x< 3$ for which $f(x)=0$, that is $4^x+5^x = 6^x$.

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I do mean that. Say, fix the exponent to be $2.5$, then find the positive integers $a,b$, and $c$.

Comment: As many pointed out, my solution gives you *some* exponent for which an integer solution exists. Of course it should be almost impossible to find a solution given an exponent: this is exactly why FLT is so difficult in the first place...

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari No one has said that there exists an integer solution when the exponent is $2.5$.